# Abrir páginas web en python 3.5.X en la misma ventana

Tags: python, python-3.x, navegador-web

Buenas, he hecho un script para lanzar varias páginas web en una sola ventana, es decir, cada url en una pestaña sin embargo, firefox sólo abre las pestañas si está iniciado,si no, lo abre en ventanas nuevas, mi código es el siguiente:

```
import os
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new("https://es5.forgeofempires.com/game/index?ref=")
webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://www.elalmeria.es/")
webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://www.ideal.es/almeria/")
webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://www.eldiario.es/")
webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://www.elconfidencial.com/")
webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://www.20minutos.es/")
webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://vozpopuli.com/inicio")
webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://www.elplural.com/")
webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://www.infolibre.es/")
webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.es/?client=firefox-b#q=rafa+es+genial&gfe_rd=cr")
#quiero estas pestañas se abran en un una sola ventana.
```

Comment: ¿has probado a abrirlas todas usando únicamente `webbrowser.open` con la *url* y el resto de parámetros por defecto? E.g., `webbrowser.open("https://es5.forgeofempires.com/game/index?ref=")`

Comment: Sí, y no va, no sé por qué

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque si firefox no está iniciado al mandarle las urls webbrowser.open() no detecta proceso abierto y abre cada pagina en un nuevo proceso. El problema es que las ordenes se envian seguidas por lo que no da tiempo a que se inicie por primera vez firefox.

Puedes usar time.sleep() después de la primera llamada para dar tiempo a que se abra pero es un poco chapuzero.

Yo lo que haría es mirar a ver si hay un proceso de firefox abierto, si lo hay pues usar webbrowser.open_new_tab(), si no lo hay se inicia un nuevo proceso y se le mandan todas las urls.

Ten en cuenta que firefox admite que se le envien varias urls de una vez.

El siguiente código funciona con Python 3.5 y Windows 10:

```
import subprocess
import webbrowser



urls = [
    "https://es5.forgeofempires.com/game/index?ref=",
    "http://www.elalmeria.es/",
    "http://www.ideal.es/almeria/",
    "http://www.eldiario.es/",
    "http://www.elconfidencial.com/",
    "http://www.20minutos.es/",
    "http://vozpopuli.com/inicio",
    "http://www.elplural.com/",
    "http://www.infolibre.es/",
    "https://www.google.es/?client=firefox-b#q=rafa+es+genial&gfe_rd=cr",
]

firefox_path = 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'

def processExists(processname):
    prog=[line.split() for line in subprocess.check_output("tasklist").splitlines()]      
    return any([task[0] == bytes(processname, 'utf8') for task in prog[3:]])

if processExists('firefox.exe'):
    for url in urls:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
else:
    subprocess.run([firefox_path]+urls)
```

firefox_path debe ser la ruta de firefox.exe, en mi caso está instalado en la ruta que aparece aqui pero compruba donde está el tuyo. Recuerda cambiar los '\' por '/' al especificar la ruta.

Las webs están en una lista lo que facilita agregar o eliminar webs y el codigo en si.

Si usas alguna distro Linux tenemos que cambiar algunas cosas (funciona en Kubuntu 16.04 y Python 3.5):

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import webbrowser



urls = [
    "https://es5.forgeofempires.com/game/index?ref=",
    "http://www.elalmeria.es/",
    "http://www.ideal.es/almeria/",
    "http://www.eldiario.es/",
    "http://www.elconfidencial.com/",
    "http://www.20minutos.es/",
    "http://vozpopuli.com/inicio",
    "http://www.elplural.com/",
    "http://www.infolibre.es/",
    "https://www.google.es/?client=firefox-b#q=rafa+es+genial&gfe_rd=cr",
]

def processExists(processname):
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(["pidof", processname])
        return True
    except: return False

if processExists('firefox'):
    for url in urls:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
else:
    subprocess.run(['firefox']+urls, shell=False)
```

Comment: Me muestra los siguientes errores:  File "C:/Users/El xaxe/Desktop/pestañas.py", line 29, in <module>
    subprocess.run([firefox_path]+urls)
  File "D:\Dapython\lib\subprocess.py", line 696, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "D:\Dapython\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "D:\Dapython\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

Comment: Comprueba que la ruta a mozilla.exe es correcta y si copias y pegas la ruta desde el explorador de windows recuerda cambiar todas las '\' por `/`. Puedes probar a no usar la ruta como en el código que puse para linux, para ello cambia subprocess.run([firefox_path]+urls) por subprocess.run(['firefox']+urls), no obstante para que esto funcione tiene que estar firefox correctamente añadido a las variables del sistema de Windows. Elc ´código funciona con python 3.5 y windows 10 correctamente. Compruba la ruta y no olvides lo de las barras inclinadas.

Comment: @ras212 si quieres puedes comprobar que no hay problemas con la ruta ejecutando esta linea en la consola interactiva o en un script: open('C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe') cambiando la ruta por la tuya que esa es la mia!! Si la ruta está bién te tiene que retornar un objeto, si algo va mal como ruta incorrecta o acceso denegado retornara un error.

Comment: Pues no me funciona, volveré a comprobarlo, muchas gracias

Comment: @ras212 si te sigue sin funcionar comenta los errores que te aparecen o que es lo que no hace correctamente. También estaria bien saber que sistema operaivo usas, los codigos están probados y funcionan perfectamente  en W10 y Kubuntu 16.04 ambos con Firefox 49.01 y Python 3.5.2. Saludos.